# How would I refactor a Rail's ApplicationController with Constants set to ActiveRecord results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, constants

I'm working on a Rails 2.1 project that has an ApplicationController similar to the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController:Base
  THIS_SITE = Site.find_by_url('www.example.net')
  ADMIN_ROLES = StaffRole.find(:all, :conditions => ["site_id = ? AND name IN (?)", ApplicationController::THIS_SITE.id, 'Administrator'])
end
```

I was unable to run tests, because in my test environment I would get an error saying THIS_SITE is nil when trying to define ADMIN_ROLES.  I fixed the issue by doing the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController:Base
  def self.this_site
    @@this_site ||= Site.find_by_url('www.example.net')
  end
  def self.admin_roles
    @admin_roles ||= StaffRole.find(:all, :conditions => ["site_id = ? AND name IN (?)", ApplicationController::this_site.id, 'Administrator'])
end
```

`ApplicationController::THIS_SITE` and `ApplicationController::ADMIN_ROLES` are used throughout the application in views, controllers, and models.  I feel that this is all wrong and dirty. Am I wrong thinking that this is wrong/dirty? If not, how can this be refactored?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in test mode is that the ApplicationController class gets loaded even before the test database is populated. And while there is no problem with using Constants per se; defining class methods moves the loading from the DB moment a bit into the future and let you run your tests.

I do think, however, that "@@this_site" in your code should probably be "@this_site".

From a sys-architects point of view both this_site and admin_roles look like per-app settings and should be moved out of the controller parts. A good place to define app-wide settings is below config/initializers or in your environment.rb

BTW: Isn't Rails 2.1 a bit on the old side?

Comment: Yes, Rails 2.1 is old, but it's what I was given to work with for the moment. The single @ character looks correct, I will test it.  You are correct that these do seem to be per-app settings, but the information is stored in the database (each application has the same code and database structure, but different data). The application assumes that a Site and admin StaffRoles are entered into the database.  Can the database information be pulled from config/initializers? And will my testing need to load the Sites and StaffRoles fixtures every time? I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, if I am not mistaken you can access the database in the initializers already. And yes, you need to load your fixtures during tests everytime. Rails, however, does this for you already.: just add all needed data in your fixtures. Just make sure you add the "fixture :models" line. However, to have your **tests** access the data in the database during initialization you must have a "prepopulated" test database; I guess 'RAILS_ENV=test rake db:fixtures:load' should load your fixtures into the database. (Note: the RAILS_ENV is way important here!)